# C# MVC 4 multiple login systems

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, entity-framework-5, asp.net-4.5

I'm creating a site that has 3 logical areas where people need to log in:

1. customers login
2. companies login
3. admin/business manager login

I'm trying to work out the best way to handle the logins.

Is it possible to use the identity model with 3 different login pages, 3 different tables etc and keep them all separate? If so how do I go about this?

Or do I need to just handle this via roles, although the data needed to be held will be vastly different and they will already have several roles on each of the 3 systems?

I'm using C# MVC 4, .Net 4.5, Wntity framework 5. Any comments or thoughts welcome as I'm struggling to get my head around on how to do it.

Has anyone implemented something similar?

Thanks.

Comment: maybe you use ASP.NET Membership with a custom table like "UserArea" and "Area" to seperate the users?

Comment: thats what i was thinking but am unsure how the auth cookie would work. when ones signed in would it class as signed in to the other systems and i then have to check which system is logged in? also how would i know which system has been logged in to or is there a way of having 3 separate cookies and keep them separate? Iv only had to do single login before so never really got in to detail of how it worked, iv just used it
!

Comment: Are you going to store the creds but just scoped by customer, companies, manager?  Or does your site have to authenticate via a customers authenication system?  (example, your creds, google or customers AD).

Comment: not quite sure i understand your question so will try and answer but may be way off what you meant. customers will be able to log in via username password, facebook connect, open id etc. companies will just be a username and password, admin will be just user name and password. the 3 sections are separated in to separate Areas on the mvc site. i would ideally like to have seperate user and seperate role tables for each of the 3 areas but not sure how to go about it

Comment: Is there a reason you don't use the same login system for all and apply three different roles to them? This sound like a text book example for using roles.

Comment: main reason i was looking not to use 1 table is that i wanted different user data storing and normally i extend the UserProfile table with extra fields to store the users data. suppose there is nothing stopping me from having the user data in 3 separate tables and leaving the userprofile table as just UserId and UserName. I was also hoping to have 3 different login pages too so if user wasnt authorised it would redirect to the relevant login page depending on which controller failed the authorize check. i will probably end up doing it as a single login in the end

Answer (score 1):

I've never done this myself, but you might want to try using the "path" parameter on the forms authentication config value to specify a separate cookie for each area.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/1d3t3c61%28v=vs.90%29.aspx

This article has a section on partitioning a site which may be useful: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff648341.aspx

Comment: can i set the froms element in the areas web.config and override the sites default web.config just for that area then?

Comment: Not sure, to be honest. In theory it sounds like it should work, but you should test it out to be sure.